# Filter Core Data by string NSPredicate

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm saving this API response in Core Data successfully:

```
    {
    "data": [{
        "result": {
            "id": 5,
            "key": "A",
            "title": "some title",
            "comments": "some comments",
            "created_at": "2019-12-16 13:42:26",
            "updated_at": "2019-12-16 13:42:26",
            "deleted_at": ""
        }
    }, {
        "result": {
            "id": 7,
            "key": "B",
            "title": "some title",
            "comments": "some comments",
            "created_at": "2019-12-16 13:45:29",
            "updated_at": "2019-12-16 13:45:29",
            "deleted_at": ""
        }
    }]
}
```

And I'm able to retrieve it from Core Data, but I need to retrieve only the array that has `"key": "A"`

So I'm trying to do it this way but getting nothing returned:

```
    func getResultA() -> [ResultsModel] {

    var retrievedResults = [ResultsModel]()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Results")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key == %@", "A")
    let result = try? privateContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {

        let id = data.value(forKey: "id") as? Int ?? 0
        let key = data.value(forKey: "key") as? String ?? ""
        let title = data.value(forKey: "title") as? String ?? ""
        let comments = data.value(forKey: "comments") as? String ?? ""

        retrievedResults.append(ResultsModel(id: id, key: key, title: title, comments: comments))

    }
    return retrievedResults
}
```

Here is the `ResultsModel` if it helps:

```
    class ResultsModel {

    let id: Int
    let key: String
    let title: String
    let comments: String

    init(id: Int, key: String, title: String, comments: String) {
        self.id       = id
        self.key      = key
        self.title    = title
        self.comments = comments
    }

}
```

I think I'm having a mistake using `NSPredicate` I need to filter only the array that have Key = A or B .

Can anyone point out the mistake please? Thank you in advance for your ideas and time!

Comment: Why an extra new model class? If you create a request `NSFetchRequest<Results>` you get `Results` objects (no type cast needed) whose properties can be accessed type safe with dot notation. The predicate is correct. Do you get items without the predicate? You can also write `format: "key == 'A'")` if the value doesn't change.

Comment: @vadian With the predicate I get: []
Without it I get: [App_Name.ResultsModel, App_Name.ResultsModel, App_Name.ResultsModel]

Comment: And all `key` properties in `ResultsModel` have a value?

Comment: @vadian You were right, The predicate is correct. I found out that they don't have a value! And that let me rewrite the API response Get method and now all works fine, thanks for pointing that up!